# listAll firebase storage order of excution

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to return after collecting all files path but the function return with empty list.

```js
async function gcsFilesListTwo(uid: string): Promise<string[]> {
    let ret: string[] = []
    if (browser) {
        const storage = firestorage();
        const listRef = ref(storage, `gs://bucket/folder`);

        listAll(listRef)
            .then((res) => {
                res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
                    listAll(folderRef).then(subRes => {
                        subRes.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
                            if (itemRef.fullPath.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                                ret.push(itemRef.fullPath)
                            }
                        });
                        return ret;
                        // I want to return here after adding all files
                        //But this happens after the function return
                    })
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("list error", error)
            });
        return ret
    }
    return ret
}
```

Comment: If you're able to declare the function async, you should not use then/catch callbacks at all.  Use await to wait for any promises to settle and get the result. This will make your code much more simple and readable.  Also avoid the use of forEach, as it does not work at all the way you expect with promises. This is a common mistake and you can learn about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing right now, you're mixing `async` with `then/catch` callbacks. It's one or the other, never both. However, as @DougStevenson also mentioned in his comment, if you want to declare your function as an `async` function, then you have to use `await` to wait for all promises to be resolved so you can get the result of the request. This solution is much simpler than using the `then/catch` callbacks.

As I see in your code, you're using a `forEach` but in the case of asynchronous calls, it will not work for sure as you might expect. So to solve this, you should create an empty array in which you should all promises and in the end simply call:

```
await Promise.all(promises);
```

More info below:

- [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer is in the comments i am posting the revised code here for a non-TS programmers like me.

```js
async function gcsFilesListTwo(uid: string): Promise<string[]> {
    let ret: string[] = []
    if (browser) {
                const storage = firestorage();
        const listRef = ref(storage, `gs://bucket/folder`);

        const res = await listAll(listRef)
        for (const folderRef of res.prefixes) {
            let subRes = await listAll(folderRef)
            for (const itemRef of subRes.items) {
                if (itemRef.fullPath.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    ret.push(itemRef.fullPath)
                }
            }
        }
        return ret
    }
    return ret
}
```